# How to read Reversible Benchmarks using CUDD library

Tags: c, binary-decision-diagram, cudd

I am working on variable ordering of binary decision diagram. Till now we have used non reversible circuits. But not we need to use Reversible Benchmarks to implement some methods. But I am not getting any way to read benchmark files(ex. blif, kiss, slif files) using CUDD library in C language. I have looked for available resources on internet.Somebody please help me to find out way.

Comment: Can you, please, post a reference to some files?

Answer (score 1):

For blif, see:

https://add-lib.scce.info/assets/doxygen-cudd-documentation/bnet_8c.html

(original URL in this post: http://vlsi.colorado.edu/~fabio/CUDD/html/bnet_8c.html#a689f42407c41e19f96d5d6d8b7129ed9)

For the other formats, [`ag`](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) didn't reveal any mention within CUDD's sources. You may want to use [ABC](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~alanmi/abc/) or [SIS](https://embedded.eecs.berkeley.edu/pubs/downloads/sis/index.htm).